# Stripline label

Tags: c#, charts

Currently, I have been doing a project on graphs on windows form. Now I have something to ask.
Is there by any chance a way to move the Stripeline label out of my chart and not have it in the chart  to something like this [What I expect it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1HM1.jpg) and also make my stripeline tinner because it is too thick

[till date what i do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJwCM.jpg) 
[What I expect it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1HM1.jpg)

This is my stripline code in case you need it

```
StripLine stripLine1 = new StripLine();
        stripLine1.StripWidth = 0.01;
        stripLine1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        stripLine1.BorderWidth = 0;
        stripLine1.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        stripLine1.IntervalOffset = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text);
        stripLine1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        stripLine1.Text = "x̅";
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(stripLine1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `StripLines` are drawn inside their `ChartArea` only.

There are at least two options:

- You can display their `Text` outside of it by coding a `PaintXXX` event, maybe like this:

---

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
    Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
    Graphics g = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;
    foreach (StripLine sl in ay.StripLines)
    {
        double v = (sl.Interval != double.NaN ? sl.Interval : 0)  + sl.IntervalOffset;

        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, sl.Text, sl.Font, new Point(
            (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(ax.Maximum),
            (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(v)),Color.Black);
    }
}
```

Fine-tuning the position, maybe by honoring the `TextAlignment` properties is up to you..

Note that this will now display the text twice; a simple solution it to make the original label transparent:

```
   YourStripLine.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
```

[image]

Also note that drawn graphics will not get exported if you serialize the chart.

---

- An alternative would be to set the secondary y-axis and add the labels as `CustomLabels`. On second thought, I think this is preferrable, at least if you don't need the secondary y-axis.

Here I do it for one stripline:

```
Axis ay2 = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2;
ay2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
ay2.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
cl.Text = stripLine.Text;
double v = (stripLine.Interval != double.NaN ? stripLine.Interval : 0)  
            + stripLine.IntervalOffset;
cl.FromPosition = v - 0.001;
cl.ToPosition = v + 0.001;
ay2.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
```

You here also will want to make the original text transparent.

[image]

Comment: Can I ask how did you make your stripline so thin as well because  mine is very thick and it is not something i wanted as well

Comment: `StripLine stripLine = new StripLine();
    stripLine.StripWidth = 0.001;
    stripLine.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    stripLine.BorderWidth = 4;
    stripLine.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;` But yours oght to be even thinner!? Are there other thing you do to them?

Comment: Note: While by default the values for BorderWidth  are in pixels per  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline.stripwidth(v=vs.110).aspx) : _If the value of the StripWidth property is greater than 0.0, the units are determined by the relevant axis scale_ - The [stripwidthtype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline.stripwidthtype(v=vs.110).aspx) may also come into play. So with the samll range of the y-axis you may need to make the stripwidth even small by a few more 0s

Comment: I set it to  0.01 because if I do not it will be hidden if I want to draw it on line 0

Comment: I know; it was my advice. Try 0.001 and see it that makes it smaller.

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Comment: Let me try to move the stripline label before i accept it

Comment: It dose help by putting my Stripline label out but now instead of just outside inside the chart it self still has the label

Comment: Yes; that's why I suggested to set its ForeColor to transparent!(2nd code snippet)